# Using Kubernetes to auto scale in google container engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Does anyone have experience in Autoscaling containers using Google Container Engine?  Containers are useful, but if I need to manually scale, and my web service has a traffic spike and people get 404's, my startup could be toast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Container (pod) autoscaling will be available in release 1.1, which will be available on Google Container Engine within a few weeks. The documentation will be available in
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/design/horizontal-pod-autoscaler.md
by the end of this week.

Comment: Ha, i was also wondering what pods were, they are google's own container format!  Thanks for answering that too.

Comment: FYI it is now available: http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/horizontal-pod-autoscaler.html